# Any reason behind the syntax difference between shared pointers and unique pointers with custom deleters

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

While both shared pointers and unique pointers in C++11 allow user defined deleters, they have notable syntax differences, as shown in the below mini example:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <memory>
class factory
{
public:
    static factory * create() {
        return new factory();
    }
    static void destroy(factory*    fp) noexcept{
        delete fp;
    }
    factory(const factory &) = delete;
    factory& operator= (const factory &) = delete;
private:
    char * p_;
    factory() {
    p_ = new char[100];
    }
    ~factory() {
        delete[] p_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef void(*fp)(factory*);

    auto del = [](factory * p) noexcept {
        factory::destroy(p);
    };

    std::shared_ptr<factory> fsptr1(factory::create(), del);
    std::shared_ptr<factory> fsptr2(factory::create(), del);
    //notice the syntax is different
    std::unique_ptr<factory, fp> ufsptr1(factory::create(), del);
    std::unique_ptr<factory, decltype(del)> ufsptr2(factory::create(), del);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason behind this is that the template class for shared pointers is defined as

```
template< class T > class shared_ptr;
```

and the template class for unique pointers is defined as

```
template<class T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>> class unique_ptr;
```

My question is: Is there any reason behind this design decision that the syntax of the two differentiates itself from each other? My naive thinking is that if the template class for shared pointers is made as

```
template< class T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>> class shared_ptr;
```

it will makes more sense. For one thing, it is consistent with the case of unique pointers, and for another, it won't instantiate when the default deleter is not well formed and the user fails to provide a custom one.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do assignation between `shared_ptr<T, Deleter1>` and  `shared_ptr<T, Deleter2>` ? with `shared_ptr<T>` you can (even if deleter are different).

Comment: One difference is that you can declare `shared_ptr` of a forward-declared class, while `unique_ptr` must see the complete definition.

Comment: What is this `destroy` static method? That's very bad design... Same for the `delete[]`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is that a good thing that one does assignment between shared_ptr<T> with different deleters?

Comment: I think it is good, but it has the overhead of erase type of the deleter. As one of `unique_ptr`'s goal is to be a free replacement of raw owning pointer, it should not have this overhead. `shared_ptr` already have some overhead (ref counting, ...).

Comment: In addition to @Jarod42 In `shared_ptr`, the deleter is "bound" to instance. IMHO, this is important. Otherwise, you could change the deleter of an instance simply by assigning to another `shared_ptr` which is going to be the last surviving. That would be fatal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `std::unique_ptr` is only storing one element, the pointer to the data it protects. This is because by default, you want to use the least amount of memory possible. But when you specify a deleter, you need also to store it. So you need to differentiate between the two versions.

See here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L2397

The storage is a specific type based on the template types.

But for `std::shared_ptr`, you don't have this constraint, you already have a counter, you need to allocate a block to store it. So you can make the deletion choice inside the allocation logic instead of outside, at the API level.

See here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L3592

The `compressed_pair` is not in the smart pointer itself, but in the allocated block.

Comment: I don't quite follow your reasoning. when ones specifies a deleter, they both need to store it.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li: EBO (Empty Base optimization) might apply.

Comment: Yes, but for `shared_ptr`, you are not storing the deleter as the unique pointer is, you allocate a block where the pointer and the counter are. So if you specify a deleter, you can allocate more to store it. This can be done in the constructor with the deleter. For unique_ptr, you have to switch statically between the two implementations.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You mean cache efficiency?

Comment: No, for the cache efficiency issue, that's where `make_shared` comes in. Modified my answer for more explanations + links to libc++ implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it.